# Stream.Length throws NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, stream

I'm trying to POST data to a Restful service and getting this error. Any help greatly appreciated.

Length = 'dataStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Position = 'dataStream.Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

here is the code

```
[WebMethod]
//public static void Main(string output)
public string webPost()
{
    //HttpWebResponse response = null; 
    string output = null;

    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://subscribers");
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    // Set the Method property of the request to POST.        
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userid", "password");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

    string EmailAddress = "test@test1.com";
    string FirstName = "first";
    string LastName = "Last";

    StringBuilder Efulfill = new StringBuilder();

    Efulfill.Append("EmailAddress" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(EmailAddress));
    Efulfill.Append("FirstName" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FirstName));
    Efulfill.Append("LastName" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(LastName));

    byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Efulfill.ToString());

    request.ContentType = "application/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1";

    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    // Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close();
    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    // Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Display the content.
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
    // Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
    return output;
}
```

Comment: It looks unlikely that the above code caused that error, as you're not actually *using* Position. Mind you, you're also not using `using` statements for your WebResponse or streams...

Comment: I tried using first but getting the same error. Can you tell me how to use the Position please?

Answer (score 5):

Duplicate of this: [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373579/stream-length-throws-notsupportedexception)

Reed Copsey answers by stating "Stream.Length only works on Stream implementations where seeking is available. You can usually check to see if Stream.CanSeek is true."

Answer (score -5):

You'll need to cast your Stream to something like a MemoryStream in order for it to be seek-able.  Length and Position are invalid on Streams where CanSeek is false.

Comment: I stand corrected. You could use something like dataStream.CopyTo(memStream).